# SQL syntax error in query

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with my MySQL Query that is displaying the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index WHERE id=1' at line 1
```

Relevant code:

```
$qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM index WHERE id= 1") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

    WHILE($d = mysql_fetch_array($qu)):

    $con = $d['content'];

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`index` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you must quote it with backticks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `index` 
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: In other words, if you can come up with a better name for that table, you might want to rename it.